# Object reference not set to an instance of an object #2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, nullreferenceexception

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    private LoginModel loginModel = null;

    #region Constructor
    public AccountController(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        this.loginModel = loginModel;
    }

    public AccountController()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Login
    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            string displayFullName = null, token = null;

            LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
            loginViewModel.UserName = userName;
            loginViewModel.Password = password;
            loginViewModel.RememberMe = rememberMe;

            ModelState.AddModelErrors(loginViewModel.ValidateLogIn());

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            //login failed than return view. 
            if (!this.loginModel.LogIn(loginViewModel, ref displayFullName, ref token))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", PortalErrors.IncorrectDataMsg);
                return View();
            }

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", PortalErrors.CommonErrMsg);
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I get the error on my above code on line if (!this.loginModel.LogIn(loginViewModel, ref displayFullName, ref token))

Can any one help with this to find what's wrong in this one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: @JohnSaunders yeah I'd agree with that too; doesn't matter how much code goes up; a null reference always boils down to the same thing, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely it's because the `loginModel` is supposed to be set in the constructor; but MVC will not fire the constructor that sets it; it'll be firing the default constructor - so by that point it's null; hence the `NullReferenceException`.

I'm going to take a guess that you've inherited this Controller from someone else; and that they have written unit tests for it - hence the additional constructor; unless, as Jon has mentioned, there is some DI framework active on the site (in which case it's misconfigured).

If there's a DI framework creating the controller - then check that it can resolve an instance of `LoginModel`.  An easy way, and good practise, is to check for a null `LoginModel` being passed in that constructor and throw an exception (typically `ArgumentNullException`; the use of Code Contracts as mentioned by another answer here is a good plan) and then run the site again.  Either you'll get the same error (in which case there's probably no DI involved), or you'll get your `ArgumentNullException` - in which case there is and it's badly configured.

If there isn't, you need to modify the default constructor of the controller to create the default instance of `LoginModel` - presumably it has roots in a Database or something like that - ultimately you'll need to look at the rest of the project's code to figure that one out.

Comment: you mean it will use the empty constructor?

Comment: yes it will; MVC doesn't know how to fill out a Controller's constructor out of the box.  Here's an MSDN lab on using Dependency Injection with MVC3 that might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618491.  It introduces the Unity DI framework.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you've got two cosntructor - one of them sets `this.loginModel` (although it doesn't check that it sets it to a non-null value); the other doesn't.

Which constructor is being called? If it's the parameterless one, then I'm not surprised you're getting that error. Do you *need* both constructors? Is this being instantiated by some DI framework?

Comment: Do i need to use DI framework if I am using both framework? How can i get rid off this error?

Comment: @updev: I asked because it's unclear how your controller is being created. Do you *need* that parameterless constructor at all?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like `this.loginModel` is null (or, it could be something within the call to `this.loginModel.Login`).

I suspect the former because you have

```
public AccountController() { }
```

where you never set `this.loginModel`.

Additionally, in this constructor

```
public AccountController(LoginModel loginModel) {
    this.loginModel = loginModel;
}
```

you didn't check that `loginModel` is not `null`. I think you remove the parameterless constructor and you should add a contract

```
Contract.Requires(loginModel != null);
```

Comment: You can need to ensure that `this.loginModel` is not `null`. I'd suggest removing the parameterless constructor, and then making sure that you're only injecting non-`null` instances of `LoginModel` into the constructor `AccountController(LoginModel loginModel)`.

Answer (score 1):

Put a debugger breakpoint on the line in question.

When the code stops there, are any of the variables null?

My guess is that `this.loginModel` is null there.  You can't call instance methods on null instances.

Comment: In that case you'll need to figure out how to get a non-null loginModel before you can call any methods on it.  For what it's worth, this might be a good place for a static method.  Most `Login` methods I've seen are stateless, and in that case a static method is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess loginModel is null. If the AccountController was instantiated with the parameterless constructor that will have caused this.